# Bootstrap DateTimpicker Angular Binding doesn't update after selection in calenderdialog

Tags: angularjs, datetimepicker, model-binding, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I have a problem with the model binding of my bootstrap datetimepicker, that doesn't update after selecting a date in the dialog.
When I directly edit the input field the binding gets triggered, but selecting doesn't update the binding.

I have a small 
[Plunker example](http://plnkr.co/edit/G6dAE4qDB2dyiBCKTpru)

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <p>Hello {{name}}! {{datum}}</p>
  <div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon add-on"><span class="fa fa-calendar"></span></span>
    <input type="text" class="form-control datetimepicker" ng-model="datum"/>                                                
  </div>
</body>


var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
  $scope.datum = new Date();

  if($(".datetimepicker").length > 0){
    $('.datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
      format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm'
    });            
  }

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Plain bootstrap doesn't work with angular. You will need/should use a bootstrap-angular binding library *instead of* the bootstrap scripts. You still use the bootstrap css/sass/less etc. Angularstrap is one such library and it doesn't depend on jquery.

When you use angularstraps datepicker it will update your binding.

The (foul, hideous, messy) alternative is to bind an event handler to the bootstrap datepicker change event and from within there call `$scope.digest()` and/or trigger a `changed` event manually on the textfield element.

Comment: It was indeed the datetimepicker that didn't work with angular.